# Open a .cfile from rtl_sdr after convert with GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio

I have a binary file (capture.bin) from the rtl_sdr tool. I convert it to a .cfile with this manual http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr#Usingthedata

Where can I get the data in this file? The goal is to get a numerical format output from the the source. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

That actually is covered by [a GNU Radio FAQ entry](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/FAQ#What-is-the-file-format-of-a-file_sink-How-can-I-read-files-produced-by-a-file-sink).

> What is the file format of a file_sink? How can I read files produced by a file sink?
>
> All files are in pure binary format. Just bits. That’s it. A floating point data stream is saved as 32 bits in the file, one after the other. A complex signal has 32 bits for the real part and 32 bits for the imaginary part. Reading back a complex number means reading in 32 bits, saving that to the real part of a complex data structure, and then reading in the next 32 bits as the imaginary part of the data structure. And just keep reading the data.
>
> Take a look at the Octave and Python files in gr-utils for reading in data using Octave and Python’s Scipy module.
>
> The exception to the format is when using the metadata file format. These files are produced by the File Meta Sink: http://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1blocks_1_1file__meta__sink.html block and read by the File Meta Source block. >See the manual page on the metadata file format for more information about how to deal with these files.
>
> A one-line Python command to read the entire file into a numpy array is:

```
f = scipy.fromfile(open("filename"), dtype=scipy.uint8)
```

> Replace the dtype with scipy.int16, scipy.int32, scipy.float32, scipy.complex64 or >whatever type you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Update
scipy.fromfile will be deprecated in v2.0 so instead use numpy library

`f = numpy.fromfile(open("filename"), dtype=numpy.uint8)`